# static allocation of block-diagonal matrix with distinct block-sizes in cpp

Tags: c++, arrays, arraylist, static

Our code expresses a matrix A of dimension n via an object of ''float[n][n]''. All computation code is based on assuming this static object type.

Now, have a block diagonal matrix D, where each block Ai has dimension ni.

By virtue of a constructor ''BDmat<{3,4,7}> D;'' we want to construct an object D such that D(i) returns Ai of type float[ni][ni], where n0=3, n1=4, n2=7.

The number of blocks and the dimension per block are given at compile time. We just do not know how to implement BDmat in a static way.

Is it possible? If yes, then how is it possible? Can you provide a way how to do it?

We tried

```
template<const size_t n, std::array<const size_t, n> q, const size_t i>
struct static_list;

template<> struct static_list<n,q,i>{
    float A[q[i]][q[i]];
    static_list<n,q,i+1> next;
};

template<> struct static_list<n,q,n>{
    float A[q[i]][q[i]];
};
```

which does not help however for two reasons:

1. We do not obtain an operator to access the i-th element. Instead, we would have to traverse through each static_list element via ''.next''.
2. The code is invalid cpp. We do not know how to change the definition of static_list based on whether i==n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since "float [ni][ni]" is a type depending on the value of ni, there is no way a generic ()-operator could return this type (the return type cannot vary by the value of the argument).

So I would propose making a Matrix-wrapper class `Mat` which is a square matrix of a given size.

`BDMat` could then allocate a simple array of floats with the size to hold all the submatrices. The ()-operator would then return a `Mat` object pointing at the portion of the array corresponding to the given submatrix.

This can be implemented as follows (running code showing the general idea, no boundary checks etc., C++20 is required):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

// Square matrix "pointer" class
class Mat
{
    std::size_t size;
    float *data;  // Points to the actual storage of size*size floats
public:
    Mat(float *s, std::size_t n): data(s), size(n) { }
    float & operator () (std::size_t r, std::size_t c) {return data[r*size+c];}  // Return reference to matrix element
};

// Square sum of array elements
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr size_t square_sum (const std::array<const std::size_t, N> &a, std::size_t i = 0U)
{
    return (i < N) ? (a[i]*a[i] + square_sum<N>(a, i+1U)) : 0;
}

// Square sum of array elements up to and not including given index
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr size_t square_sum_part(const std::array<const std::size_t, N> &a, std::size_t i)
{
   return (i > 0) ? (a[i-1]*a[i-1] + square_sum_part<N>(a, i-1)) : 0;
}

// Block diagonal matrix class
template <const std::size_t n, std::array<const std::size_t, n> q> class BDMat
{
  float data[square_sum<n>(q)];
  public:
    // Get reference to the given submatrix
    Mat operator () (std::size_t i) {return Mat(&data[square_sum_part<n>(q,i)], q[i]);}
};

int main()
{
    BDMat<3, {3,5,7}> bdmat;
    Mat d2 = bdmat(2);
    d2(1,0) = 4;
    std::cout<<d2(1,0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining why there can be no solution to what I seek in your very first sentence.